# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/StringDeserializer

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am currently learning how to use `apache-storm` and `apache-kafka`. I've tried to solve the problem by looking for other dependencies to add in the pom, but all the solutions that I found were related to `apache-spark-streaming`. You can find below the `code` and the `pom`.

the `code`:

```java
package analytics;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.storm.Config;
import org.apache.storm.LocalCluster;
import org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter;
import org.apache.storm.generated.AlreadyAliveException;
import org.apache.storm.generated.AuthorizationException;
import org.apache.storm.generated.InvalidTopologyException;
import org.apache.storm.generated.StormTopology;
import org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpout;
import org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpoutConfig;
import org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseWindowedBolt;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )throws Exception, AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException, AuthorizationException
    {
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        
        KafkaSpoutConfig.Builder<String, String> spoutConfigBuilder = KafkaSpoutConfig.builder("localhost:9092", "velib-stations");
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "city-stats");
        spoutConfigBuilder.setProp(prop);
        KafkaSpoutConfig<String, String> spoutConfig = spoutConfigBuilder.build();
        builder.setSpout("stations", new KafkaSpout<String, String>(spoutConfig));
        
        builder.setBolt("station-parsing", new StationParsingBolt())
            .shuffleGrouping("stations");
        
        builder.setBolt("city-stats", new CityStatsBolt().withTumblingWindow(BaseWindowedBolt.Duration.of(1000*60*5)))
            .fieldsGrouping("station-parsing", new Fields("city"));
        
        builder.setBolt("save-results",  new SaveResultsBolt())
            .fieldsGrouping("city-stats", new Fields("city"));
        
        StormTopology topology = builder.createTopology();

        Config config = new Config();
        config.setMessageTimeoutSecs(60*30);
        String topologyName = "velos";
        if(args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("remote")) {
            StormSubmitter.submitTopology(topologyName, config, topology);
        }
        else {
            LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
            cluster.submitTopology(topologyName, config, topology);
        }
    }
}
```

the `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>analytics</groupId> 
<artifactId>analytics</artifactId> <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>analytics</name> 
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

    <storm.version>2.4.0</storm.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>4.11</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-kafka-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

Comment: As answered previously, search the content of the jar file. And remove kafka-clients version 3.0.0. Storm transitively uses only 0.11

Comment: I followed the procedure you explained earlier and the class is not in the jar (sorry I didn't mentioned it in the explanations). I'm using kafka-clients because without that, I've got "package org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer does not exist"

Comment: Even if I remove, the kafka-clients and the part of the programm that uses it, I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It exists when you remove the starter import

```bash
$ jar tf target/analytics-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar | grep kafka | grep StringDeserializer
org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/StringDeserializer.class
```

```xml
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

    <storm.version>2.4.0</storm.version>
    <storm.kafka.client.version>3.2.0</storm.kafka.client.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- provided -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>${storm.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- compile -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-kafka-client</artifactId>
        <version>${storm.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>${storm.kafka.client.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- tests -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```